# How to add custom inline styles in MkDocs material theme

Tags: css, mkdocs

I've been searching for a way to add custom styles to my markdown pages. I've been able to add "extra_css" to the yml file, but that seems to only affect the generated html. For example, I was able to add a custom style for images that causes ALL  items to be centered.

I know there is a way to add attributes using something along the lines of

```
{: #someid .someclass somekey='some value' }
```

So this is a two part question:

1. Where do I create the styles? In my custom css file declared in the yml?

Example:
extra_css:
   -custom.css

2. How to I reference (apply) them inline in my markdown?

Comment: Markdown doesn't have anything to do with YAML. Maybe you're using something like Jekyll?

Answer (score 5):

> Where do I create the styles? In my custom css file declared in the yml?

Yes, create a file in your [docs_dir](https://www.mkdocs.org/user-guide/configuration/#docs_dir) (default location is `docs/`) with the same name as you listed in the [extra_css](https://www.mkdocs.org/user-guide/configuration/#extra_css) config setting of your `mkdocs.yml` configuration file. Then you can define any CSS you want within that file. More information is provided in the [Customizing a Theme](https://www.mkdocs.org/user-guide/customizing-your-theme/) section of the documentation.

> How to I reference (apply) them inline in my markdown?

You will need to enable the [Attribute List](https://python-markdown.github.io/extensions/attr_list/) extension. In your `mkdocs.yml` configuration file, include the extension in the list of [markdown_extensions](https://www.mkdocs.org/user-guide/configuration/#markdown_extensions).

```
markdown_extensions:
    - attr_list
```

Then in your Markdown documents you can use attribute lists to assign classes, etc to various elements.